# Sending a message to a Standard SNS topic which contains MessageGroupId and MessageDeduplicationId will never be received?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I created a standard SNS topic and add a email subscription to it. I send a message to this topic like this:

```
const command = new PublishBatchCommand({
      TopicArn: "myStandardTopicArn",
      PublishBatchRequestEntries: messages.map(message => {
        return {
          MessageGroupId: "someGroupID",
          MessageDeduplicationId: getUUID(),
          Id: getUUID(),
          Message: JSON.stringify(message.data),
 
        };
      }),
    });

    try {
      await this.snsClient.send(command);
    } catch (e) {
      // there is no error
      throw e;
    }
```

There is no exception being thrown but I also do not receive any email notification.

As soon as I remove `MessageGroupId` and `MessageDeduplicationId` it works.

Is that the expected behaviour? I would expect to get either an exception or that those two attributes are just ignored and the email notification is send.

If this is the expected behaviour, is there something in the documentation regarding this? I was not able to find anything about this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/preview/client/sns/command/PublishBatchCommand/). I assume that those attributes are for FIFO topics but I also could not find anything in the documentation which specifically tells you not to use them when sending to a standard topic

I also could not find any information in the documentation that for `FIFO` topics only the `SQS` protocol for subscription is available...

Answer (score 0):

MessageDeduplicationId and MessageGroupId keywords are reserved for FIFO topics only.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/publish.html

If you accidentally use any of these reserved keywords with a standard SNS topic, an exception should be thrown similar to :

`An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the Publish operation: Invalid parameter: MessageGroupId Reason: The request includes MessageGroupId parameter that is not valid for this topic type`

`An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the Publish operation: Invalid parameter: MessageDeduplicationId Reason: The request includes MessageDeduplicationId parameter that is not valid for this topic type`